# Laravel/Docker - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am using Laravel 9, Docker and Gitlab CI.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: code.scarsgaming.net:5050/beastburst/beastburst-website:latest

services:
  - mysql:5.7

variables:
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_USERNAME: root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
  APP_ENV: testing


stages:
  - test

feature_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - cp .env.example .env.testing
    - composer install
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan config:clear
    - php artisan migrate
    - php artisan test
```

The interesting part is that command `php artisan migrate` run just fine and runs all the migrations. However when it comes to running `php artisan test`

I get the following error:

```
$ php artisan test
Warning: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.
   PASS  Tests\Unit\ExampleTest
  ✓ that true is true
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\HomePageTest
  ⨯ the homepage runs fine
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ShopTest
  ⨯ the shop home page runs fine
  ⨯ supporter product
  ---
  • Tests\Feature\HomePageTest > the homepage runs fine
   PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }
```

Here is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_CONFIG_CACHE" value="cache/config-testing.php" force="true"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing_db" force="true"/>
        <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show your config/database.php -> connections. and value of DB_CONNECTION in .env.example

Comment: I agree with Bob, try setting `DB_HOST` to `mysql` in your phpunit.xml file